# Flutter Slider how to Show Label instead of Values?

Tags: flutter, slider

In Flutter, Slider, I want to show label instead of Values. The idea is for Search If I want to specify it at City level ( the lowest radius of search)
[image: Lowest radius for search]

```
And next at County
```

[image: County level search]
Next at State level [image: 3rd level of search]
Next at Country [image: Country]
and so on , last being at World Level ( the highest).

Currently Slider only displays numerical values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below code snippet

```
class DemoContent extends StatefulWidget {
  const DemoContent({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DemoContent> createState() => _DemoContentState();
}

class _DemoContentState extends State<DemoContent> {
  double _searchLevel = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Slider(
          value: _searchLevel,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              _searchLevel = value;
            });
          },
          max: 4.0,
          min: 0.0,
          divisions: 4,
          label: _getLabel(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  String _getLabel(){
    String label = '';
    if(_searchLevel == 0.0){
      label = 'City';
    }else if(_searchLevel == 1.0){
      label = 'County';
    }else if(_searchLevel == 2.0){
      label = 'State';
    } else if(_searchLevel == 3.0){
      label = 'Country';
    }else if(_searchLevel == 4.0){
      label = 'World';
    }
    return label;
  }
}
```